# How to test subscription code after pipe(takeWhile(...)) in Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I'm surprised I haven't been able to find an answer to this despite a lot of searching...

I'm trying to test that my subscription code is doing the right thing.  I've done this countless times before in Angular 2, but we just started a new project so we're using the latest Angular which has picked up a re-write of rxjs that changed the chaining to piping and now I have no idea what to mock or how to do it.

Given:

```
  constructor(private media: MediaObserver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.active = true;

    this.media.media$.pipe(takeWhile((ev) => this.active)).subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
      if (change.mqAlias === "xs" || change.mqAlias === "sm") {
        this.stackFooter = true;
      } else {
        this.stackFooter = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

How do I write a karma/jasmine test to make sure that this.stackFooter is being set correctly when the media service fires an event?
I tried to spy on various things (media$, "pipe"), for example, but it appears the takeWhile() returns a new Observable which I don't seem to have any access to?  How can I test this?  Or, is this not a recommended pattern anymore and I should just be doing something else completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it's returning a new Observable, but you do not care about Observable itself you care about the stream that it contains, try to do this:

### In your test

```
let mockMediaSubject: BehaviorSubject<MediaChange>;
...
beforeEach(() => {
   mockMediaSubject = new BehaviorSubject({});
   TestBed.configureTestModule({
      ...
      providers: [ 
         { 
             provide: MediaObserver, 
             useValue: { media$: mockMediaSubject.asObservable() }
         }
      ]
   });
});

...
it("should set stackFooter to true when media$ emits 'xs' as mqAlias", () => {
   mockMediaSubject.next({mqAlias: 'xs'});

   expect(componentInstance.stackFooter).toBeTruthy();
});
...
it("should set stackFooter to true when media$ emits 'sm' as mqAlias", () => {
   mockMediaSubject.next({mqAlias: 'sm'});

   expect(componentInstance.stackFooter).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Wow, it was difficult to type it into that editor. If i missed something and it won't work add comment with my name so i will see it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  The tests now fail with: Failed: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?[object Object]?, ...]
I also had to add "as MediaChange" in a couple places.

Comment: So do you still have a problem?

Comment: Error is because I had "provider" instead of "provide" for defining the MediaObserver.  Doh!

Comment: I've accepted this as the best answer even though I didn't use it verbatim.  I wound up creating a separate mock object with: `media$: Subject<MediaChange> = new Subject<MediaChange>();` as a member and then a constructor with `spyOn(this.media$, "subscribe").and.callThrough();`.  I provided this to the test case via `providers: [ { provide: MediaObserver, useClass: MediaObserverMock}],`. The rest was basically what was specified in the answer though.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that at least some part of answer helped you!

Comment: Can you post the code to your solution?  It's a year later, and I'm not finding a very obvious solutions despite a lot of searching.

Comment: I'm quite stunned that this is the only answer I can find on internet about this - does this mean thousands of angular apps that use MediaObserver just don't test it?